# Remove everything but the domain with PHP

Tags: php

My current js formula removes http://, https://, www and anything after '/'.

```
   function cleanUrl(url) { 
        return url.replace(/^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?/gi,"");
    }
```

E.G:
http://www.google.com/piza
returns google.com

How can I do remove everything but the domain in one step but with PHP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url).

```
$domain = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

Do note that www.example.com and example.com are technically entirely separate entities that can point at totally different sets of records.

Answer (score 2):

You could use preg_replace with your current regex and get the same result:
 http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: You'd want to drop the `g` pattern modifier though (wonder why it is there in the first place?)

Answer (score 0):

The function `parse_url()` is quite powerful, and the example usage from [php.net](http://php.net/parse_url) will shed some light on what kinds of things you can do with it:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the regex you have (with a little modification) and Use [`parse_url()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/parse_url) to do the main work:

```
function cleanUrl($url) { 
    return preg_replace('/^(www\.)?/i',"", parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
}
```

As [ceejayoz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605111/remove-everything-but-the-domain-with-php/7605130#7605130) wrote, you might want to keep `www.` as part of the domain name.

Answer (score -4):

There is a much easier way ;)

```
<?php
   echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, unless you want the domain name for any of the trillions of URLs *not* hosted on your server.